# How can I fetch the current dollar price of BNB in a Solidity smart contract?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, remix, blockchain, etherscan

How can I fetch the current dollar price of BNB in a Solidity smart contract? Are there any recommended APIs or secure, decentralized methodologies for this?Is there a way to fetch the dollar price within the contract on the Binance Smart Chain mainnet without incurring gas fees?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chainlink Data Feeds provide a secure, reliable, and decentralized source of off-chain data to power unique smart contract use cases for DeFi and beyond.

Use Chainlink:
https://data.chain.link/bsc/mainnet/crypto-usd/bnb-usd

https://bscscan.com/address/0x0567f2323251f0aab15c8dfb1967e4e8a7d42aee#readContract#F10

[image]